# How to access PostgreSQL server from Laradock?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-artisan, laradock

I've attempted to access my PostgreSQL database from both a Laravel project, DBeaver and Artisan. Accessing it from Laravel project or Artisan (`$ php artisan migrate`) always results in:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> - Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Because I'm not relying in my Laradock settings and I'm not familiar with Laravel in general, I did re-download Laradock with default settings, but situation continues same.

Partial laravelProject/.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=default
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Partial laradock/.env:

```
POSTGRES_VERSION=alpine
POSTGRES_DB=default
POSTGRES_USER=default
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

Environment used to run Artisan:

```
$ docker-compose exec --user=laradock workspace bash
```

I installed Laravel in this environment using `composer global require laravel/installer`.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=yourprojectdatabase
DB_USERNAME=default
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

**To connect using DBeaver:**

```
Host: localhost 
Port: 5432
Database: you can leave it empty
Username: default
Password: secret
```

Click on the PostgreSQL tab right there in Connection.

Make sure "Show all databases" is checked.